# Achieve table layout with String.Format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to format a string with the Format() method
unfortunately i get this result with a foreach loop:

Code:

```
output += String.Format("{0,17} {1,48}\n\n", "Name", "Description " );

Console.WriteLine(output);

string outputloop;

foreach (IMetricContract contract in metrics)
{      
     outputloop = String.Format("{0,17} {1,48}\n", contract.Name, contract.Description);                
     Console.WriteLine(outputloop);
}
```

Result:
[image]

You can see that the elements are in a different position, but i have defined the same values.
Anyone knows an solution?

Edit:

```
outputloop = String.Format("{0,-17} {1,-48}\n", contract.Name,
```

I also tried this with negative values for the position but then i get this

Result:
[image]

The Result should be look like this (Edit with Imageeditor)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to take the first character of the string to be put in a position, it seems the method is doing that with the last character this would explain the uncorrect format

Comment: Yeah, that's called right justify, which it seems to be doing exactly correct. Show an example how this _should_ be formatted.

Comment: @Sayse yes the heading is also on a different position but i handled by setting the foreach elements from 17 to 16, the bigger problem are the elements who are not in the right position

Comment: If you are trying to change justification, try using negative numbers for the second parameter. So `{0,-17}` and `{1,-48}`.

Comment: my guess is that he is surpised to see the title 'description' not aligned

Comment: @saye i want the foreach elements to be printed out in the same  lineposition?!

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri i tried this also with negative values, but then the foreach elements are leftbounded on the site but i wanted them to be in position under the 'Name' Value

Comment: @ArturKaraev I've updated title to hopefully reflect what you are looking for. Claiming that function work "incorrect" whey it does exactly what you tell it to (as opposed to what you want) is not necessary best way to explain problem. Feel free to revert/improve edit, but at least try to edit *desired* output while doing so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My english is not the best, i speak german and russian ;)

Comment: @ArturKaraev thanks for update. Note that you've changed original image... Consider using text with code formatting instead of images.

Comment: @ArturKaraev or if you don't want the highlighting to happen, wrap pre-formatted text in `<pre> </pre>` tags and it will preserve the original text you paste in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i found out how to solve this task, instead of the format function i used the padright function for strings in c#. 
This two sites gave me help:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/padright

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is my code:

```
foreach (IMetricContract contract in metrics)
            {
                name = contract.Name;
                desc = contract.Description;

                Console.Write("".PadRight(13,'#')+name.PadRight(41,'i'));
                Console.WriteLine(desc + "\n");

            }
```

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, I think you want negative numbers, as in:

```
outputloop = String.Format("{0,-17} {1,-48}\n", contract.Name, contract.Description);
```

This makes it aligned to the left (instead of to the right).

Whether you use positive or negative numbers, when the actual number of characters exceeds the absolute value of `48` (in our example), the "extra" characters go outside the "field" to the right.

Comment: I think you may be right but I'm still confused as to what the op is after, [here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FormatItem) to the docs that explains the alignment, I'm deleting my other comments :)

Comment: @ArturKaraev Do not forget to put in minuses in the heading line as well, so `String.Format("{0,-17} {1,-48}\n\n", "Name", "Description")` in the beginning.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thank you for helping, but the 'table' must be align not on the start of the screen, it should be left from the middle

Comment: Then you need to do math, cut the width in half minus half of the string length. Doing some quick math in my head you want about `output += String.Format("{0,6} {1,19}\n\n", "Name", "Description " );`

Comment: @ArturKaraev More interesting, what should happen when some contract descriptions are longer than 48 characters? Maybe you want to cut off the characters after the 48th one?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I thought about a linebreak after a specific number of characters

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes it is a tricky math problem, iam on my work to solve this, hopefully i can post an answer soon